# React Query Prefetching Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-query

I've just started converting my application over to use react query. I'm new to using this library, so I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how this is supposed to work, but it seems to me like the prefetching I'm doing isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have an expensive API call that I want to have prefetched after a user logs in, so that when they navigate to the page where the expensive API data is needed, there is a "perceived" performance increase.

What I've done so far:

On the home landing page:

```js
queryClient.prefetchQuery(["requisition", auth.token, auth.id], () =>
  getRequisitionsAllData(auth.token, auth.id),
);
```

My custom hook:

```js
export const useRequisitionQuery = (token, id) => {
  const queryOptions = { staleTime: 300 };
  return useQuery(
    ["requisition", token, id],
    () => getRequisitionsAllData(token, id),
    queryOptions,
  );
};
```

And then in the component that needs it:

```js
const { isLoading, isError, data, error, isFetching } = useRequisitionQuery(
  token,
  id,
);
```

From what I can tell, the prefetch is working on the landing page:

[image: landing page]

But then for some reason when I navigate to the next page, it seems like instead of using the cached data, the query is called again from scratch (and the page doesn't receive the data right away)

[image: On the page that should be getting prefetched data]

The table that is being populated by the data from the query also shows nothing until this network call finishes, and `console.log` on the data also returns `[]` until this call finishes.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? I'm under the impression that the data should load immediately if it's been cached.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT for more details about how I'm navigating between pages:

I'm using react router with a RequireAuth component wrapper. So in App.js (create-react-app):

```jsx
<Router>
  <MasterNavbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/SignIn" element={<SignIn setToken={setToken} />} />
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <HomeLanding />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/TrackRequisitions"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <TrackRequisitions />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>;
```

RequireAuth is just a wrapper that checks to make sure the user has a valid token:

```js
if (!auth.token || !auth.id || !auth.access) {
  return <Navigate to="/SignIn" state={{ from: location }} />;
}
return children;
```

And then the actual routing event happens in the navbar:

```jsx
<NavButton navTo="Track Requisitions" link="/TrackRequisitions" />;
```

NavButton component:

```jsx
export default function NavButton(props) {
  return (
    <Button
      sx={{
        justifyContent: "left",
        "&:hover": {
          cursor: "pointer",
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          "& .button-text": {
            textDecoration: "underline",
          },
        },
      }}
      color="inherit"
      href={props.link}
    >
      <Typography className="button-text" color="black" fontWeight={500}>
        {props.navTo}
      </Typography>
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Comment: How are you navigating between pages?

Comment: I'm using react router, I'll edit the post with some more information

Comment: @Phil something else that I noticed that I'm not sure is relevant that I'll mention anyways is: if I'm on the /TrackRequisitions page and the data has all loaded, and then I navigate to another page, and then I hit the "back" button on my browser, the table is immediately populated as if I'd never left the page. This is new behavior that didn't occur before I implemented react query, and this is what I would expect the prefetching to also do, right? Is this issue I'm seeing because the component hasn't mounted yet maybe?

Comment: You need to use a React Router `<Link>` component in order to avoid full page loads when navigating. I think this answers your question... [Can you use Material-UI Link with react-router-dom Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63216730/283366). See also https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/

Comment: @Phil You've just saved me in more than one way. Thank you so much Phil.